# Windows Azure Multi-region VMs and SQL Server

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, file-storage

I am moving my website to windows azure. majority of my users are from India and USA. the website uses a SQL Server database and file system where users can upload images and view them.

I'm thinking about creating 2 VMs one in West US and another one in Southeast Asia and use a traffic manager to load balance between my web servers, but I don't know how to set up the database and file share. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Traffic Manager can connect to VMs on any region over a public endpoint. In your case, you will have to create two public endpoints, one for each VM. Then, you can put Traffic Manager in front of these two public endpoints.
Similarly, the VMs can connect to SQL over its own public endpoint.